# How can I access application generated html source code through a perl program?

Tags: html, ajax, perl

There is generated source code in application tag. I have already tried using LWP of perl, but it does not extracts the generated source code.

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
my $link = 'http://www.scc.virginia.gov/docketsearch#recentActi­ons';
my $code = get($link);
print $code;
```

In div id="applicationHost" tag, no source code is displayed, but on the actual webpage we can see the content.

Comment: Please refer this snapshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5xBlM.png

Answer (score 2):

The page uses Javascript to make the recent actions appear.  You see it in your web browser because you have previously clicked on the appropriate link, and this is cached.  However, if you start a new session in the browser (such as by opening a private window of your browser), you will see that it comes up blank as well.

In order to solve this, you can't use LWP.  You will need to use a Perl module that mimics a web browser and supports JavaScript.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861319/how-can-i-get-started-with-web-page-scraping-using-perl) for a discussion of some possibilities.